# iOS - converting to fmp4 (from mp4/m4a) and streaming it

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, fmp4

So I didn't managed to find any code about this issue.
I have recorded an mp4 file(audioFile.mp4) and now i want to stream it through socket , yet i have problem in converting.
I know that there is the ffmpeg(https://www.ffmpeg.org/) platform yet i didn't see any code of that.
Would appreciate any idea.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var requestManager = RequestManager()

var socket: WebSocket?

var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!

@IBOutlet weak var recordBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var playBtn: UIButton!

var fileName: String = "audioFile.mp4"

var soundRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?
var soundPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.socket?.delegate = self

    setUpRecorder()
    playBtn.isEnabled = false

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .measurement, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func getDocDirector() -> URL {
    let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return path[0]
}

func setUpRecorder() {


    let audioFileName = getDocDirector().appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    let recordSettings: [String: Any] = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                                         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue,
                                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
                                         AVEncoderBitRateKey: 16000,
                                         AVSampleRateKey: 16000]

    do {
        soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFileName, settings: recordSettings)
        soundRecorder?.delegate = self
        soundRecorder?.prepareToRecord()
    } catch {
       print(error)
    }
}

func setUpPlayer() {
    let audioFileName = getDocDirector().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    do {
        soundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileName)
        soundPlayer?.delegate = self
        soundPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
        soundPlayer?.volume = 1.0
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

@IBAction func recordAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if recordBtn.titleLabel?.text == "Record" {
        soundRecorder?.record()
        recordBtn.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        playBtn.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        soundRecorder?.stop()
        recordBtn.setTitle("Record", for: .normal)
        playBtn.isEnabled = false
    }
}

@IBAction func playAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if playBtn.titleLabel?.text == "Play" {
        playBtn.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        recordBtn.isEnabled = false
        setUpPlayer()
        soundPlayer?.play()
    } else {
        playBtn.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        recordBtn.isEnabled = false
    }
}

func openSocket() {
    getUrl(success: { [weak self] (url) in
        self?.socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: url)!)
        self?.socket?.connect()
    }) { (e) in
        //
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do exactly, and what is going wrong, e.g. any error messages or incorrect output.

Comment: @AJarofClay i am trying to convert mp4 to fmp4 yet didnt find any tool fir that.

Comment: Editing your description to make it clearer that you are converting from mp4 to fmp4 should help you get an answer (I have never used swift).

Comment: @AJarofClay if you will look closely you will see that i wrote "iOS - converting to fmp4 (from mp4/m4a)"
In the code i just creating the mp4 and with all the respect the example is Minimal, Complete and Verifiable.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that info in the title!